# How does http://to./ work?

Tags: internet, dns, http

So I noticed this on Jeff's twitter. They don't have a tld, it seems?

How've they done this? Magic, bribery, or did a no-tld tld open up recently?

Comment: Same question just popped up over on ServerFault with multiple answers. :) http://serverfault.com/questions/90737/how-the-heck-is-http-to-a-valid-domain-name

Comment: @JMD: Here I was thinking I was going mad from lack of coffee... I thought I'd just seen this question.

Comment: `http://.to`, `http://to` and `http://to.` no longer work in 2013 as they apparently did in 2009.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that the way it works is simply who ever owns the TLD `.to`, simply set up an A record for the TLD itself and are providing this service.

For example, `google.com` and `google.com.` are actually the same address.

You can also access this site via `http://to`

Some domains use this technique to redirect you to where you can purchase domains from, this place seems to offer a free service.

Comment: better explanation? I do this all the time... I set up dns records for http://work which is a map, and then there is extras such as server.work server2.work etc....

Comment: It doesn't redirect here - http://www.tonic.to/ ... I think that this is actually whoever owns the .to domain names set this up based on the fact that to.com (in your example) is a different website

Comment: The server seems to be down (but DNS still resolves).

Answer (score 4):

Just to ensure people don't miss JMD's comment:

Many more answers at Server Fault's [*How the heck is `http://to./` a valid domain name?*](https://serverfault.com/questions/90737/how-the-heck-is-http-to-a-valid-domain-name)