# How does the http://to./ domain work?

Tags: url, url-shortening, tld

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does http://to./ work?](https://superuser.com/questions/78408/how-does-http-to-work)

Jeff Atwood ([@codinghorror](http://twitter.com/codinghorror)) posted a tweet a few days ago, congratulating http://to./ for launching the shortest URL shortener, and breaking every URL matching regex. I was wondering how the heck does this work?

Comment: Didn't the tweet also link directly to SF: http://serverfault.com/questions/90737/how-the-heck-is-http-to-a-valid-domain-name ?

Comment: Agree that it's been asked and answered on ServerFault

Comment: This was asked last week - me and John T both posted answers but I can't seem to find the question anywhere :S Looks like it has vanished

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/78408/how-does-http-to-work/

Comment: The tweet did not link directly to the SF question but his next tweet 12 minutes later absolutely did.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, someone has put an A record on the top level domain .to so anyone visiting will go to this service.

It is sort of like how in offices, you usually have http://intranet and http://jobs.intranet and more... It is all clever uses of DNS.

Comment: s/clever/plain/